# How to use Polymer components with ClojureScript + React?

Tags: polymer, web-component, clojurescript, google-closure-compiler

I'm using Polymer components with ClojureScript + Reframe (actually, at the moment, I have just one Polymer component working). My component is mostly stateless (a drawing tool for Dicom images), so it plays nicely with Reframe. I use HTML + callbacks to communicate with it. It works nicely, but I'm not using ClojureScript advanced compilation. I haven't used advanced compilation before and have some questions about its use:

1. As I understand, Polymer isn't compatible with Google Closure. Is that still the case?
2. If I'm using just HTML/callbacks to talk to the component, do I still have problems with name mangling? I suppose that I am safe with the HTML part, but am I going to have problems with the callbacks? Such as `[component-x {... :on-mouse-down   (dispatch-canvas-event editor-id)}]`
3. What happens to the javascript portion of the WebComponent during compilation? Does it get changed, even if I don't call any function directly (just HTML/callbacks)?
4. If I do have to call a function in a component, any examples of how to write an Extern file for a Polymer component?

Comment: There's no solution right now but you could write a wrapper library.

Comment: To address your questions. Polymer can be compiled by the closure compiler (advanced mode is trickier though), see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CplQdSo7lkE. Name munging can likely be handled with ^export and some extra work. The JS will be minified, optimized through tree shaking + dead code eliminiation, and variable munging. It's still usable though, code splitting would be a good idea. This could help with writing Polymer externs https://github.com/PolymerLabs/extern-generator.